# Storing width in react context vs hooks

Tags: reactjs

In a production level app is it better to store the screen width in context or use a custom hook to store the device width?

The main code is:

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  }, []);
```

Can someone correct me if Im wrong but every time the screen resizes, storing the width in context would re render the entire app for every pixel width changes so there would be a crazy amount of re renders. My thought was to tell my manager that storing it in a hook is better because only the elements using the screen width would be re rendered.

Comment: why do you need to store it at all? You don't have to listen the resizing to update the screen size in state. `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` always contain the actual size and you could use it directly in a place where you need it, without putting it to the state

Comment: In react window.innerWidth doesnt update and re render components unless its in state

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

As for your question,

> storing the width in context would re render the entire app for every pixel width changes so there would be a crazy amount of re-renders

I'd say that depends where you `consume` data

[image]
[Source](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/)

Checking the above workflow, you can see only a part of `Component 2`, which use `consume` to listen to `provider` changes, gets re-rendered.

> My thought was to tell my manager that storing it in a hook is better because only the elements using the screen width would be re rendered.

Similarly, if you use custom hooks, it will have the same effect as Context API. Where you use hooks, that place will get re-rendered.

> In a production level app is it better to store the screen width in context or use a custom hook to store the device width?

`window` itself is used globally, so I'd suggest using Context API as a better place to keep your `window` events/states. It can be used effectively in both class-based component and function-based components (hooks only can be used in function-based components)

In the function-based component, you can call `useContext` hook to get data

```
const windowProps = useContext(Context)
```

In class-based component, you can get data via `Context.Consumer`

```
<Context.Consumer>
{(windowProps) => <Component {...windowProps} />}
</Context.Consumer>
```

Lastly, as for your crazy re-rendering concern, you also can use debounce to delay updating states continuously.

**OLD ANSWER**

You can use debounce to avoid continuous state updates on `resize`. I'm using `setTimeout` for the debounce logic

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);
const timer = useRef();

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    if(timer.current) {
       clearTimeout(timer.current) //if an user try to resize the screen again, we reset timer (no triggering state update logic)
    } 
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
       setWidth(window.innerWidth);
       setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    }, 500) //delay state change after 0.5s
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  }, []);
```

If you look for a simpler solution, you can use [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce). The logic will be like this

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(handleWindowResize,500));
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', debounce(handleWindowResize,500));
  }, []);
```

If you're not sure what debounce is, you can check [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/). This is also very useful for scrolling position updates

Comment: My question was should I store width in a hook state or store it in the react context provider?

Comment: I updated my answer for your question @CryptoGeek981